# Getting an active IP address from a list of IP address in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am stuck while getting ip4 address from my computer with 2 network card and 1 wifi card.

The code i am using to get IP address is this :

```
    'Get Network Information
    hostName = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()
    Dim hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName)
    Dim addressList As New List(Of IPAddress)
    For Each address In hostEntry.AddressList
        If address.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
            addressList.Add(address)
        End If
    Next
```

The problem is, if i used this code to get the ip address into a text box, it didn't always show the ip address my computer is currently active :

```
    teIP4.Text = addressList(0).ToString
```

Edit : I am trying to connect to SQL Server via LAN but still in a and inserting my ip address to the database for further use, so i need to get the active ip address.

Is there anyway to specify which IP Address is currently active from code? Thanks!

Comment: If it's local then you can use the loop back adapter 127.0.0.1, or the machine name, or (local).

Comment: Thank you @SamAxe, but by local I mean in a network, not in my workstation.

Comment: Ah.  Then local is the wrong word.  On your own network you should be able to use the machine name.